# How to force Symfony to use Composer 2

Tags: symfony, composer-php, symfony-cli

My Symfony 4.4 application was buit with Composer 1.x. Now I need to switch to Composer 2. But I'm unable to do the switch, because Symfony CLI uses Composer 1 no matter what.

I've both composer1 and composer2 installed:

```
# ls -la /usr/local/bin/ | grep composer
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  2354438 dic 31 18:06 composer
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  2000535 set 16 16:28 composer1

# /usr/local/bin/composer1 --version
Composer version 1.10.22 2021-04-27 13:10:45

# /usr/local/bin/composer --version
Composer version 2.2.3 2021-12-31 12:18:53
```

But when I run `symfony composer --version`, it uses composer 1.x.

Back in '20, Fabien [wrote](https://symfony.com/blog/composer-2-support-in-symfony-cli-and-symfonycloud)

> For Symfony CLI, running symfony composer checks the version of Composer used in the composer.lock file and tries to find a Composer binary named composer1 or composer2.

So the problem is that I need to update the `composer.lock` of my application to use composer2. Still, I cannot find any reference to the composer versione being used.

So, as per title: how can I update my `composer.lock` to use Composer 2?

Comment: "I need to update the composer.lock of my application to use composer2" - what does that mean? Why not simply use `composer update` to do this?

Comment: Please read about the advantage of `symfony composer` before downvoting the question, thanks.

Comment: Please read about the usage of `symfony composer`. As it relies on checking the lock file from your project, I doubt it can be used to change the Composer version to be used

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found out by trial and error. It was enough to run

```
# /bin/php7.4 /usr/local/bin/composer update
```

(that's the composer2 executable).

Composer worked it's magic and now I get

```
# symfony composer --version
Composer version 2.2.3 2021-12-31 12:18:53
```